# Switch to npm for create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I recently installed yarn on my machine but was using npm before. For my current project in React I want to use npm again.

However, if I run create-react-app it is built with yarn.

How can I switch so that it is created with npm?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use the `--use-npm` flag:

```
create-react-app my-project --use-npm
```

Answer (score 35):

If it's an existing project you can just remove `yarn.lock` and continue using it with `npm`.

Comment: Likewise, if you want to move from npm to yarn, just delete package-lock.json and use yarn